# GraphQL Java client library

Tags: java, client, graphql

I am looking for a java *client* library for GraphQL. 
This is to use for server-to-server communication, both in java.
No android, not javascript... just java.
Apollo is the nearest answer, and it seems like it is for Android only, not for plain-java applications.
Lots of examples about build server in java, nothing about client.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a few clients available, all taking different approaches.

1. [Apollo Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) - Originally intended for Android, but equally usable in any Java project. Someone also made a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/Sparow199/apollo-client-maven-plugin) for it.
2. [Shopify's GraphQL Java gen](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen) - Similar to what
   wsdl2java does, for example, but not wrapped into a Maven plugin.
   Generates a nice client, but requires Ruby... It's worth investigating if the Ruby dependency can be satisfied using JRuby JAR.
3. [Nodes](https://github.com/americanexpress/nodes) A GraphQL JVM Client designed for constructing queries from standard model definitions. By American Express
4. [Manifold](http://manifold.systems/docs.html#graphql) can be used as a GraphQL client
5. [graphql-kotlin](https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/graphql-kotlin/) GraphQL Kotlin provides a set of lightweight type-safe GraphQL HTTP clients. The library provides Ktor HTTP client and Spring WebClient based reference implementations as well as allows for custom implementations using other engines. Type-safe data models are generated at build time by the GraphQL Kotlin Gradle and Maven plugins.